# Setting legend area proportion on webmap produced by qgis2web for a mobile phone/tablet

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin, qgis2web

[image]I have produced a webmap using qgis2web tool using the open layers option. It is hosted on a remote server. Viewing it on a desktop/laptop is fine. However when i try to view the same using a phone,i find that the legend is taking up most of the screen space!

How do i edit the code to allow the legend to take up specific percentage of available screen space?

@image is how it is displaying on a mobile phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I would consider setting the layers list to `collapsed` in the qgis2web dialog rather than `expanded`, as that is probably most appropriate for mobile use.

However, if you do want an expanded list, you can make it narrower. Find your exported map, and open `resources/ol3-layerswitcher.css` in a text editor. Find this code:

```
.layer-switcher .panel {
    padding: 0 1em 0 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 4px solid #eee;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    display: none;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Add `max-width` as follows:

```
.layer-switcher .panel {
    padding: 0 1em 0 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 4px solid #eee;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    display: none;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 150px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Obviously change the value to suit your needs. If you reexport via qgis2web, you'll have to repeat this change.